# ask multiple directions in one call to mapBox

Tags: mapbox

I use the api mapbox-java-services on my app, who use a paying account for mapbox.

I need to know which is the shortest path from 4 different destination. For that I use the direction client . How can I do it without having to call mapbox 4 times?

I have try to merge all the path into one , but the result is often to complex to be computed by mapbox and end-up in timeout. Also, sometime one of the destination is not reachable, so all destination fail, not only the unreachable one.

How can I have the direction of 4 different locations without having to call mapbox 4 times?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know which is the shortest path from 4 different destination.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you provide more information about what your end goal is?

Do you want to go **back** to the original location? If so, it sounds like the Mapbox Optimization API is what you should use:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/optimization/

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/generate-an-optimized-route/